# WPF EF debug release database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, debugging, publish

There are plenty of questions relating to a database swap between debug and release/production in ASP/Web environments, however I'm using WPF and deploying an application through the built in updater.

How do I configure entity framework to give me a debug database on a specific server, say dbDebug on AA-SQL-DEV for a debug build and once published connect to a different database say dbProduction on AA-SQL-PRO?